# How to ensure that files uploaded by users do not contain any XSS code

Tags: javascript, xss, threat-mitigation

I have been working on providing the security related to the XSS attacks. My website only allows following mime-types:

`XML, CSV, HTML, PLAIN, VND_WAP_WML, APPLICATION_ZIP, APPLICATION_PDF, APPLICATION_VND_FDF, APPLICATION_MS_WORD, APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, APPLICATION_VND_MS_POWERPOINT, APPLICATION_X_VISIO, IMAGE_GIF, IMAGE_PNG, IMAGE_TIF, APPLICATION_VND_MS_OUTLOOK, APPLICATION_DOWNLOAD, APPLICATION_JSON`

I have sanitized HTML files using antiSamy. How can I ensure that the data in the files is safe before uploading the data to database, and prevent persistent XSS attacks?

Comment: Or maybe, "How to ensure that malicious files uploaded by users do not result in an XSS attack when used." ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't, really.

You can reduce the chances of content-sniffing running HTML by serving files with a `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` header, and try to avoid them being treated as HTML pages by serving with `Content-Disposition: attachment`, but still you have older browsers to worry about, and browser plugins. (For example Java's broken SOP and Flash's crossdomain XML sniffing.)

Best workaround if you have to accept user-uploaded files is to serve them from a separate domain, so that any XSS attack can't compromise the main site.

Comment: but additional domain means extra bucks!

Comment: You can use a subdomain but it's not quite as good. It prevents XSS in JavaScript, but it still allows cookie injection from the subdomain into the parent domain. (And if you have a web site running on the bare domain it can read cookies from there too, so you would have to make sure to provide access to the site only through `www.`.) Domain names are so cheap nowadays it's not generally worth it though.

Comment: Agree with you bobince :)

Answer (score 0):

you cant.

pdf allows inclusion of otherwise encoded / compressed data, strings can be appended to images etc pp; you'd need to check every file that gets uploaded by a 3rd software (sourcefire build something like such a parser for pdf/zipped - data to extend snort, using lua iirc; but i dont know the state of that project)

Comment: @(that guy from over there) How can packet sniffing help in preventing xss?

Comment: packet-sniffing cant help either; it was just an example. what you need is some process that analyses the uploaded data for you with generic parsers for each file-format. the problem is: you can embed different payload in pdf or office-docs that get rendered client-side and is invisible for packet-sniffers. 

snort was just an example for the use of such a parser.

Comment: In the end, it turns out a tough nut to crack. :(

Comment: @Prerit: exactamente

Comment: grazie seno`r !! :)